# Find combinations of genome without any package

Tags: r, seq

I want to find how many combinations of genome are found in a sequence. I mean for binary combinations: AA,AT,AG,AC,... 16 combinations like that;or for 3-elemented combinations ATG,ACG,... 64 combinations like that. I know how to do that with a package and I will write down it here. I want to create my own code to perform this

seqinr package is perfect on its job. That is the code that i used for;

```
install.packages('seqinr')    
library(seqinr)    
m = read.fasta(file='sequence.fasta')     
mseq = m[[1]]     
count(mseq,2)   # gives how many binary combinations are found in the seq     
count(mseq,3)   # gives how many 3-elemented combinations are found in the seq
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple thing to do is just something like this:

```
# Generate a test sequence
set.seed(1234)
testSeq <- paste(sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace = T), collapse = "")

# Split string into chunks of size 2 and then count occurrences
testBigram <- substring(testSeq, seq(1, nchar(testSeq), 2), seq(2, nchar(testSeq), 2))
table(testBigram)

AA AB AC BA BB BC CA CB CC 
10 10 14  3  3  2  2  5  1
```

Here is a way using a "function factory" (https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-factories.html).

The 2-element and 3-element combinations are n-grams of size 2 and 3. So we make this n-gram function factory.

```
# Generate a function to create a function
ngram <- function(size) {
  function(myvector) {

    substring(myvector, seq(1, nchar(myvector), size), seq(size, nchar(myvector), size))

  }
}

# Assign the functions names (optional)
bigram <- ngram(2)
trigram <- ngram(3)

# 2 element combinations
table(bigram(testSeq))

AA AB AC BA BB BC CA CB CC 
10 10 14  3  3  2  2  5  1 

# count of 2 element combinations
length(unique(bigram(testSeq)))

[1] 9

# counting function
count <- function(mseq, n) length(unique(ngram(n)(mseq)))
count(testSeq, 2)

[1] 9

# and if we wanted to do with with 3 element combinations
table(trigram(testSeq))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The first code that you wrote is what I want.

Answer (score 2):

This is a slow way to do it. I am certain it is faster in the bioconductor package.

```
# some practice data
mseq = paste(sample(c("A", "C", "G", "T"), 1000, rep=T), collapse="")

# define a function called count
count = function(mseq, n){
  # split the sequence into every possible sub sequence of length n
  x = sapply(1:(nchar(mseq) - n + 1), function(i) substr(mseq, i, i+n-1))
  # how many unique sub sequences of length R are there?
  length(table(x))
}
```

Actually just checked and this is pretty much how they did it:

```
function (seq, wordsize, start = 0, by = 1, freq = FALSE, alphabet = s2c("acgt"), 
    frame = start) 
{
    if (!missing(frame)) 
        start = frame
    istarts <- seq(from = 1 + start, to = length(seq), by = by)
    oligos <- seq[istarts]
    oligos.levels <- levels(as.factor(words(wordsize, alphabet = alphabet)))
    if (wordsize >= 2) {
        for (i in 2:wordsize) {
            oligos <- paste(oligos, seq[istarts + i - 1], sep = "")
        }
    }
    counts <- table(factor(oligos, levels = oligos.levels))
    if (freq == TRUE) 
        counts <- counts/sum(counts)
    return(counts)
}
```

If you want to find the code for a function use getAnywhere()

```
getAnywhere(count)
```